# Regular Expression to replace between tags

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

I have the following CSS lines (example):

```
body, greed { background-image: -webkit-gradient(from( #fff ), to( #ebebeb )); }
```

I want to replace the **commas** to **$ sign** between { and } with Regular Expression (I'm using Notepad++)

This is what I got for now: **{(.*)}**

Comment: Please show what your desired output is to make sure we understand what you're asking for.

Comment: The desired output must be the comma, but not between body and green, but inside the { and }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
,(?=[^\{\}]*\})
```

And replace by `$`.

The positive lookahead `,(?=[^\{\}]*\})` makes sure there's a closing brace ahead and no braces in between.

Result:

```
body, greed { background-image: -webkit-gradient(from( #fff )$ to( #ebebeb )); }
```

Comment: the first two backslashes could be saved. I mean the two in `[..]`

Comment: @Kent Correct. I find that escaping them makes it a little more readable, especially for people new to regex, so I left them just in case.